# Replacement for .Filtered in NEST 5.5.0

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to convert this block of code but can't find the correct definition to replace .Filtered accepting Action < FilteredQueryDescriptor< T >> selector.
I have upgraded to NEST version 5.5.0 and here's the block of code that I'm trying to convert to work using higher version of NEST:

```
        UserView defaultUserView = new UserView();

        SearchDescriptor<MyOrder> _searchDesc = new SearchDescriptor<MyOrder>();

        _searchDesc = _searchDesc                    
                .Index(MyIndex)
                .Type(MyType)
                .Query(mq => mq.Filtered(QueryDescriptor(defaultView)))
                .SearchType(SearchType.Count)
```

Here's the QueryDescriptor:

```
    private Func<SearchDescriptor<MyOrder>, SearchDescriptor<MyOrder>> QueryDescriptor(UserView userView)
    {
        Func<SearchDescriptor<MyOrder>, SearchDescriptor<MyOrder>> result;

        result = delegate(SearchDescriptor<MyOrder> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Query
            (
                query => query.MatchAll()
            )
            .Query(f => f.Bool(CommonHelper.GetFilters(userView)));
            return descriptor;
        };

        return result;
    }
```

EDITED:Here's the CommonHelper.GetFilters(userView):

```
 public static class CommonHelper
 {
    public static Func<BoolQueryDescriptor<MyOrder>, BoolQueryDescriptor<MyOrder>> GetFilters(UserView userView)
    {
       Func<BoolQueryDescriptor<MyOrder>, BoolQueryDescriptor<MyOrder>> 
       result= delegate (BoolQueryDescriptor<MyOrder> descriptor)
         { 
             switch (userView.UserView)
             {
                  case UserView.1:
                       descriptor.Must(OldDefaultFilter());
                       break;
                  case UserView.2:
                       descriptor.Must(OldDefaultFilter())
                              .MustNot(MustNotDefaultFilter());
                       break;
             }
             return descriptor;
          };
        return result;
```

}
   }

Comment: Can you share your CommonHelper class?

Comment: Hi @Md.AbdulAlim, kindly see CommonHelper.GetFilters above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilteredQueryDescriptor<T>` was deprecated in NEST 2.x and removed in NEST 5.x, in line with the change in Elasticsearch in the respective major versions.

Moving forward, use a `bool` query instead with a `must` clause for the query and a `filter` clause for the filter.